# Angularjs accordion is not working in my project

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs accordion whose data is coming from json,but here its working fine but in my project accordion is not working.Is there any other way to do it.Below is my code.I am new to angularjs.Thanks in advance.

### HTML

```
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <style>
    .test1{
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div>
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="test in items">
      <div class="test1" ng-click="handleClick(test)">
                {{test.title}}
      </div><br>
      <div class="test2"  ng-show="selectedItem==test"> {{test.location}}</div><br>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [
  {  
    "title": "firstitem",
    "location": "location1"
   },
  {    
    "title": "seconditem",
    "location": "location2"
   },
  {    
    "title": "thirditem",
    "location": "location3"
   }
];


$scope.handleClick = function (test) {
        $scope.selectedItem = test;
      }

});
```

Comment: you should load jquery before angular. There's also no reason to use an older version of angularjs. You should use latest (1.6.3...?? I think) Where are you using the carousel?

Comment: ok sorry that is accordion by mistake I wrote carousel

Comment: @DevinFields That is not a correct statement.  There are definitely reasons to use older versions of angularjs.  Check out the Migrating from 1.5 to 1.6 docs and you'll see a lot of changes that some devs might not like.

Comment: @BShaps If he were migrating a project, I would understand, but there is nothing in this code that would influence him towards an older version. Both our points are true.

Comment: @DevinFields Why are you assuming that this is the only code in prasad's project?  Both of our points can't be true, they're mutually exclusive.  There are significant changes in 1.6 that many devs don't like.  Since that is a valid reason to use an older version, your statement is not true and could mislead devs who look at this question.

Comment: @BShaps 'I am new to angularjs.' That is why I am assuming. How can he know that he doesn't like the changes between 1.5.x to 1.6.x if he is new to the framework? I don't want to convolute these comments, so I'll leave it there. Again, I understand your point, but mine is still valid in this scenario.

Comment: @DevinFields You can't know how he feels which is why you shouldn't have instructed him to change his version of a script when doing so doesn't help him at all.  If you want to insist you are correct that is your perogative.  I just wanted to make sure people were aware that what you said isn't a factual statement and that reasons do exist to use 1.5 over 1.6

Comment: Ok no issue...may be due to version also I will check and let you know

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  $scope.items = [
    {
      title: 'firstitem',
      location: 'location1'
    },
    {
      title: 'seconditem',
      location: 'location2'
    },
    {
      title: 'thirditem',
      location: 'location3'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
 <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>   
<body >
<div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <uib-accordion-group heading="{{test.title}}" ng-repeat="test in items">
      {{test.location}}
    </uib-accordion-group>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can create Angularjs accordion using the following way easily.

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>   
<body >
<div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">  
  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <uib-accordion-group heading="{{test.title}}" ng-repeat="test in items">
      {{test.location}}
    </uib-accordion-group>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  $scope.items = [
    {
      title: 'firstitem',
      location: 'location1'
    },
    {
      title: 'seconditem',
      location: 'location2'
    },
    {
      title: 'thirditem',
      location: 'location3'
    }
  ];
});
```

Check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/25669/) for more clarification.
Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help,actually we are using <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script> version of library in our project.but this is not working with this version

Comment: This code is not working with this version <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>

Comment: Ok. It may be useful for others.:)